# EDITOR: subsidiary program 'emacs -nw' not found

Tags: emacs, editors, sdiff

I have set up

```
$ echo $EDITOR
emacs -nw
```

I was wondering why it is not found here, and how I can solve the problem? Thanks.

```
$ sdiff -o sdiff.out f1 f2
1 2 3                                 | 2 3 4
%e1
sdiff: subsidiary program 'emacs -nw' not found
```

I don't know why an option in `$EDITOR` is a problem, and where it is required in `sdiff` source code? I guess it is here http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/tree/src/sdiff.c#n459

```
prog = getenv ("EDITOR");
if (prog)
  editor_program = prog;
```

and here http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/tree/src/sdiff.c#n1035

```
execvp (editor_program, (char **) argv);
```

or http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/tree/src/sdiff.c#n1018 and http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/tree/src/sdiff.c#n1024. I am not sure what the program is doing.

For comparison, the following works perfectly fine:

```
$ eval "$EDITOR"
```

Answer (score 5):

It's apparent that `sdiff` attempted to execute a program named exactly `emacs -nw`, which didn't exist. Your intention was for `sdiff` to call `emacs` with an option `-nw` followed by the file(s).

The behavior is confirmed by looking at the [sdiff source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/tree/src/sdiff.c#n1018), where `sdiff` populates the preferred editor --directly-- into argv[0], which puts the `<space><dash>nw` together with the `emacs`.  You could also confirm that `sdiff` is generally working correctly by setting `EDITOR=emacs` and observing that it opens emacs.

If you need the option when opening emacs, then my suggestion would be to create a wrapper script:

```
$ cat emacs.sh
#!/bin/sh

vi "$@"
```

Just kidding, of course. You'd use:

```
$ cat emacs.sh
#!/bin/sh

emacs -nw "$@"
```

... and then set `EDITOR=/path/to/that/emacs.sh`

Comment: Did you hack my machine??? The former is exactly what emacs.sh has on it!!! 

Comment: Small suggestion to use `exec` when invoking emacs from the script.

Comment: Indeed, using exec would be a microscopic improvement; one that I noticed only after finding the proposed duplicate. Thanks for the edit!